# How does the $T$-$S$ diagram change in the Otto cycle with increased compression ratio?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

How will the $T$-$S$ diagram look in the Otto cycle if we add the same amount of heat but increase the compression ratio? Is my drawing correct, meaning that the vertical lines representing isentropic reactions will increase, and entropy will decrease after constant volume heat addition?

[image: otto]